# Spring Boot + React

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, react-router

### Intro

I'm trying to implement very simple CRUD app, it's going to be a single-page application with few Rest Controllers.

### Problem

The problem which I encounter during implementation is that, even though my script written in React JS is built successfully with webpack and injected into static page "index.html" the content is not displayed.

**Cases when the content is displayed correctly:**

- Running it separately with webpack-dev-server,
- Opening index.html page in any browser on its own

**When it is not:**

- when I try to run it from IDE as Spring Boot Application with Controller mapping I keep getting just the blank page.

### Project photo

[Structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ooCu.png)

Here is my **HomeController** responsible for mapping to static page under "/"

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome() {
    return "index";
 }
}
```

Here is my **index.html** page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
   <meta name="description" content=""/>
   <meta name="author" content=""/>
   <title>React</title>
   <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
   <link
       href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/
       cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Custom Fonts -->
   <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
       type="text/css"/>
   <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
        family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" 
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="react"></div>
   <script src="../static/built/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Probably the last thing which could be helpful is **app.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

import Archives from "./pages/Archives";
import Featured from "./pages/Featured";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";

const app = document.getElementById('react');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Featured}/>
      <Route path="archives(/:article)" name="archives" component={Archives}/>
      <Route path="settings" name="settings" component={Settings}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

### Reflection

Firstly I was thinking that could be somehow the problem with using the same URLs in router and controller, but after changing them it has not resolved the problem. So I run out of any ideas.

Comment: how are you tring to serve your react app in spring boot? resource/static?

Comment: yes, as on attached picture in link, I have defined static index.html page in /resources/templates/  within which I'm trying to inject my built script defined in /resources/static.

Comment: spring boot by default expose only the static directory try to move the index to the static

Comment: no sorry I'm wrong I need to investigate more

Comment: another question did the blank page have some html inside? cause it seems it's trying to serve something

Comment: I have html indeed but mixed up with js as React allow for that kind of thing, when I dive into console in my browser it's saying that bundle.js "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" . Mapping is correct as title correspond to the one from index.html.

Comment: ok, try to reloa with the network tab open in the developer conolse. You should see the 404 and see the complete path where your index is searching

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/static/built/bundle.js

Comment: so it seems correct... can you reach the bunlde.js directly from the browser?(now I need to know :D even If I need to ask you 100 more questions )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `/static/` in the path to your `bundle.js` when using the defaults provided by Spring Boot.

In your `index.html` update your script tag to:

```
<script src="/built/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: that worked like a charm, thanks man, added also th:src{} instead of src so it would be context-aware